# list all running configuration on kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I wish to list all configurations active on a kafka broker. I could see the configurations in server.properties files but that's not all, it doesn't show all configurations. I want to be able to see all configurations, even the default ones. Is this possible?
Any pointers in this direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command which list the current configuration of a kafka broker. However if you want to see all the configuration parameters with there default values and importance it is listed here

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that programatically through Kafka AdminClient (I'm using 2.0 FWIW - the interface is still evolving):

```
        final String brokerId = "1";
        final ConfigResource cr = new ConfigResource(Type.BROKER, brokerId);
        final DescribeConfigsResult dcr = admin.describeConfigs(Arrays.asList(cr));
        final Map<ConfigResource, Config> configMap = dcr.all().get();
        for (final Config config : configMap.values()) {
            for (final ConfigEntry entry : config.entries()) {
                System.out.println(entry);
            }
        }
```

[KafkaAdmin Javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html)

Each of config entries has a '*source*' property that indicates where the property is coming from (in case of broker it's default broker config or per-broker override; for topics there's more possible values).